# Printing arrays without a separator

Tags: java, arrays, printing

I've been struggling for a while with this. I was assigned to do a program that takes the input of the user and outputs the same word, but written in asterisks, to do this, I had to do an array for every single letter in the alphabet. Like this:

```
String A [][]= new String [5][5];

        A[0][0]=" ";
        A[0][1]= "*";
        A[0][2]="*";
        A[0][3]="*";
        A[0][4]=" ";
        A[1][0]="*";
        A[1][1]=" ";
        A[1][2]=" ";
        A[1][3]=" ";
        A[1][4]="*";
        A[2][0]="*";
        A[2][1]="*";
        A[2][2]="*";
        A[2][3]="*";
        A[2][4]="*";
        A[3][0]="*";
        A[3][1]=" ";
        A[3][2]=" ";
        A[3][3]=" ";
        A[3][4]="*";
        A[4][0]="*";
        A[4][1]=" ";
        A[4][2]=" ";
        A[4][3]=" ";
        A[4][4]="*";
```

I've been trying to print them to see how it's gonna look after I finish it, and I've been trying to print it with `System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(A));`
but the output I get is like this, which is just the first line of the array

```
[[ , *, *, *,  ], [*,  ,  ,  , *], [*, *, *, *, *], [*,  ,  ,  , *], [*,  ,  ,  , *]]
```

instead of like this:
[image]

Is there an argument I have to add to the println I already have or do I have to use another print method?

Comment: Can you print it using, for example, a `for-loop`? I'm confused here...

Answer (score 2):

`Arrays.deepToString` does not behave as you expect it.

What it does is recursively print each array of an array, hence the `deep` word.

Here a part of it javadoc which is pretty clear of what it prints :

> The string representation consists of a list of the array's elements,
>   enclosed in square brackets ("[]"). Adjacent elements are separated by
>   the characters ", " (a comma followed by a space). Elements are
>   converted to strings as by String.valueOf(Object), unless they are
>   themselves arrays.

You could print what you want easily with a for-loop :

```
for (String[] A1 : A) {
    for (String A2 : A1) 
        System.out.print(A2);

    System.out.println();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As @Jean-François Savard said, `Arrays.deepToString` does not support `newline` by the end of array.

but In `Java8`, you can do it by using `stream` to short your code:

```
Arrays.stream(A).forEach(t -> System.out.println(String.join(" ", t)));
```

Comment: But the OP specified in the title he want to print without separator. Your code will print bracket and comma.

Comment: all we know, there is no other way can do it expect loop 2, I just provide a another way? right?

Comment: No, your way does not do the sampe. As I said, it prints brackets and comma which is what the OP want to avoid.

Comment: *I've been trying to print them to see how it's gonna look after I finish it,* he just wants to check it by the output.

Comment: But then he gave an example of how he want to see them, and there is no delimiters as per the title of the question.

Answer (score 0):

Do a double for-loop. Example:

```
for(int i=0; A.length; i++){
    for(int j=0; A[i].length; j++)
        System.out.print(A[i][j]);
     System.out.println();
}
```

And if that doesn't work just switch the i and the j variable around in

```
System.out.print(A[i][j]);
```

When you use the deepToString() method, it puts the array into the format that you received. If you just want raw data, then you use the method that I showed you, using a for-loop.

Comment: Thanks! it does work!... kind of, had to tweak it a TIIIINY bit, instead of i<4, I had to switch it to i<=4 and that did the trick

Answer (score 0):

You can print it like:

```
public void print(final String[][] array) {
  // make sure 'array' has "something"
  for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++) {
      System.out.printf("%s", array[i][j]);
      // ...or use this since I'm not sure the dashes were there on purpose
      //System.out.printf("%s", " ".equalsIgnoreCase(array[i][j]) ?
      //    "-" : array[i][j]);
    }
    System.out.println();
  }
}
```